# Regenerate = Recover or Renew?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

My brother just took his exam and there was this reading passage about deforestation of rain forests. The questions were pretty easy; however, there was this question:

> Which of these is the closest in meaning to the word "regenerate" in paragraph 2?
>   A. **repeat** B. **refine** C. **recover** D. **renew**

And this question needed information from the following line from the passage:

> [...] Some logged forests, if left alone, can **regenerate** in a few decades.

Apparently, the answer is either **recover** or **renew**. So what do you think is the most correct answer in this context?

Comment: I think *renew* is the better answer because *regenerate* carries the notion of *new growth*, as opposed to an ailing part 'getting better'. The argument for *recover* is probably that the forest *as a whole* might be said to be 'getting better', but that probably stretches *regenerate* past what is comfortable. Compare: when a lizard regrows its tail, we say the *tail* regenerates, not the *lizard*. Although *regenerate* is applied to the forest as a whole in your example, I think it's still understood to refer to *new* growth.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comprehensive input, Lawrence :)

Comment: I'd say *recover* since deforestation is an injury to the overall forest. But I don't think there's a strong argument against either word.

Comment: @Jim Mack 'Renew' is closer in meaning to 'regenerate' than 'recover', as Lawrence explains. A problem is that it's not used that often in the intransitive sense, and 'recover' sounds more natural here (but is not 'closest in meaning', as is required).

Comment: Hello, Khang. ELU vastly prefers reasonable research to be done and supplied along with the question. What do dictionary definitions suggest here?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth In pure dictionary terms you're right of course, but considering the context I still think *recover* is a better fit. "Meaning in context" is one of the tags on this. (-:

Comment: Hey Edwin, I did do some research on these words. Apparently, according to Google, renew means "resume (an activity) after an interruption.", which has no relation to the context of the passage. However, my brother's teacher suggested "renew" as a better option so I was pretty confused.

Comment: @Jim Mack At least the examiners don't make the crass mistake of not accepting one of the answers when choosing one rather than the other is quite close to hairsplitting.

Comment: Choosing one particular definition / sense from several offered in a dictionary has to be done using common sense. One wouldn't interpret 'corner' in 'Giggs took a corner' to mean 'he pinched _the bit of the field furthest from the centre spot_'.  And some dictionaries are better in some places than others.  Look at the senses given by Webster's in the comment below. And [RHK Webster's](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/renew) sense (10) intransitive: be restored to a former state.

Answer (score 2):

**Renew** means to make something old appear like new or start again some process that was happening in the past. For example, you could renew your subscription/contract or you could renew your old car.

But, speaking of forests, you can't renew trees which have already been cut down. You must wait for the forest to **recover** and leave the new trees grow up. IMO, **recover** has the closest meaning to **regenerate** because both mean something that happens without the need of human interaction.

Comment: [Webster's NWCD](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/renew) gives the relevant sense: << renew verb ... intransitive 8. to become new or as new again; be renewed >> And [RHK Webster's](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/renew) sense (10) << intransitive: be[come] restored to a former state. >> (no volitional agency stipulated). However, I _would_ say that ' ... renew itself ...' _would_ be more idiomatic than the middle voice usage here.

Answer (score 0):

*Regenerate* and *renew* both imply the forest grows back to what it was before the incident described (in this case, logging). However, *recover* implies that the area gets back to a stable, more-or-less acceptable state, which may be different from the original; maybe a different type of tree grows there, or perhaps the balance of wildlife is different. Therefore, I see *renew* as the correct answer.

As an (inverted) example, if someone's hand is cut off, they may *recover* in that they can regain most of their previous abilities (e.g. they lose their dominant hand and learn to write with the remaining one). But there is no documented case, to my knowledge, of a hand being *regenerated* or *renewed*, which would mean they grow a new hand in place of the one that was lost.